# Read Avro Buffer encoded messages with ConsumeKafka (NIFI)

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-nifi

I am new to NIFI(and not much experience with Kafka), and I am trying to consume the messages that the producer is generating. To do this job, I am using the the ConsumeKafka processor on NIFI.

The messages are arriving (I can see them on the queue), but when I check the queue, and try to view the messages, I can only see the content with hex format (f.e: in original format I can see a message that says: No viewer is registered for this content type).

The messages that the producer is sending are encoded avro buffer (this is the reference I have taken: https://blog.mimacom.com/apache-kafka-with-node-js/) And when I check the consumer from the console, each message has this format:

```
02018-09-21T08:37:44.587Z      @02018-09-21T08:37:44.587Z      @
```

I have read that the processor UpdateRecord can help to change the hex code to plain text, but I can't make it happen.

How can I configure this UpdateRecord processor?

Chears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Instead of `ConsumeKafka`, it is better to use `ConsumeKafkaRecord` processor appropriate to the Kafka version you're using and configure `Record Reader` with an `AvroReader` and set `Record Writer` to the writer of your choice.
- Once that's done, you have to configure the `AvroReader` controller service with a Schema registry. You can use `AvroSchemaRegistry` where you would specify the schema for the Avro messages that you're receiving in Kafka.

A quick look at this tutorial would help you achieve what you want: https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries